# How to show an element with click function

Tags: jquery, show, fadein

I'm having trouble having a bubble show on click.  Either show or 
         fadeIn  would  do. Here is my script and html.

```
     $("button").click(function(){
     $("#oval").show();
      });
     <div id ="oval">
     <p><em>"Hello, my name is Ahmoo. I'm having some kittens soon. 
        Would you like  one?</em>   </p></div>
     <button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:none` to the DIV.Jquery show working with only `display:none`

```
<div id="oval" style='display:none'>
    <p><em>"Hello, my name is Ahmoo. I'm having some kittens soon. 
        Would you like  one?</em> 
    </p>
</div>
<button>Click</button>



$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function () {
    $("#oval").show();
});


});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/73DpS/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok.

Make sure you call your code after document-ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#oval").show();
    });
});
```

If this doesn't help, make sure your `div` **can** be visible at all.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean re div visible at all?

Comment: I mean, that if you add a `display` other than `none`, you can see the `div`